# t.test on a data.table in long format

Tags: r, data.table

I am getting an error on a `data.table` which I don't understand. What I want to do is to perform multiple `t.test`s as post-hoc analysis. So here some sample data:

```
dt <- data.table(
  expand.grid( list( SID = rep( paste0( "x", 1:3), 3 ), MID = paste0( "y", 1:5) ), stringsAsFactors=FALSE ),
  A = rnorm(45),
  key = c("SID")
)    dt

   SID MID          A
1:  x1  y1 -1.4451214
2:  x1  y2 -0.6141025
3:  x1  y3 -1.0388595
4:  x1  y4 -0.8098261
...
```

This gives me then a strange error:

```
dt[ , list( t.test( x=.SD[ J("x1"), A ], y=.SD[ J("x2"), A ] )$p.value ) , by = MID ]
Error in setkey(ans, NULL) : 
  x may no longer be the character name of the data.table. The possibility was undocumented and has been removed.
```

I have no clue what this means, but the desired output would be something like

```
   MID p.x1.x2
1: y1  0.1
2: y2  0.2
3: y3  0.3
4: y4  0.4
5: y5  0.5
```

And this is what I would be able to do in the end (just to give you the full picture):

```
combinations <- lapply( as.data.frame( combn( unique(dt$SID), 2 ), stringsAsFactors=FALSE ), identity )
combinations
$V1
[1] "x1" "x2"

$V2
[1] "x1" "x3"

$V3
[1] "x2" "x3"    

test.tab <- lapply( combinations, function( .sid, .dt ){
  dt[ , list( t.test( x=.SD[ J(.sid[1]), A ], y=.SD[ J(.sid[2]), A ] )$p.value ) , by = MID ]
}, .dt = dt )
test.tab <- as.data.table( as.data.frame( test.tab ) )
```

Any idea how to avoid the error is appreciated. Any other approach to get the same result would be also fine.

Comment: You've not set a key for your data.table. You need it for using `J(.)`. In any case, I think what you're looking for is : `dt[ , list( t.test(x=A[SID == "x1"], y=A[SID == "x2"])$p.value ) , by = MID ]` (which in this case will just give back an error that there are not enough values).

Comment: @Arun thanks, indeed there were still two mistakes: 1) There was only one observation per combination SID/MID 2) I forgot to select the according column in the `t.test` so it shpuld have been `t.test( x=.SD[ J("x1"), A ], y=.SD[ J("x2"), A ] )`. I fixed that in my example. And if there is now better answer, you solution works fine. But what I don't understand: I did set the key when defining `dt` to `SID`. So why is this not considered in `.SD`. And what does the error mean?

Comment: Beasterfield, `.SD[J("x1"), A]` would still give a `data.table`. What you should do to give a vector, if you're really wanting to use `.SD` is: `.SD[J("x1")][, A]`. That is, you should do: `dt[ , t.test(.SD[ J("x1")][, A], .SD[J("x2")][, A])$p.value , by = MID ]`.

Comment: You can directly try this to replicate your error: `t.test(dt["x1", A], dt["x2", A])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this line in `t.test.default`:

```
y <- y[yok]

Error in setkey(ans, NULL) : 
  x may no longer be the character name of the data.table. The possibility was undocumented and has been removed.
```

You can print the function on your screen with `stats:::t.test.default` (which is what's run for your version of t.test).

Here, `y` is expected to be a vector where as you're providing `.SD[J("x1"), A]` which is a `data.table` (as I mentioned under comments).

In your case, `yok` evaluates to:

```
       SID    A
 [1,] TRUE TRUE
 [2,] TRUE TRUE
 [3,] TRUE TRUE
 [4,] TRUE TRUE
 [5,] TRUE TRUE
 [6,] TRUE TRUE
 [7,] TRUE TRUE
 [8,] TRUE TRUE
 [9,] TRUE TRUE
[10,] TRUE TRUE
[11,] TRUE TRUE
[12,] TRUE TRUE
[13,] TRUE TRUE
[14,] TRUE TRUE
[15,] TRUE TRUE
```

and `y` is :

```
    SID           A
 1:  x2 -0.80390040
 2:  x2  0.34483953
 3:  x2  2.08006382
 4:  x2  0.87859745
 5:  x2  1.04123702
 6:  x2  0.13653716
 7:  x2  0.58482554
 8:  x2 -0.78308074
 9:  x2 -0.02177879
10:  x2 -0.33626948
11:  x2  0.17005957
12:  x2  1.15227502
13:  x2  1.21486699
14:  x2  0.93856469
15:  x2 -0.54720535
```

And doing `y[yok]` would give you this error as the key of "y" is set to "SID".

In short, you're asked to provide a vector of values for x and y arguments whereas you provide a data.table and since it's keyed with column "SID", and it internally runs `y[yok]` which is two columns, the error happens there. If you instead do: `as.data.frame(.SD[J("x1"), A])` then you'd see that this error will vanish but you'll still get some other error (this error vanishes because there's no "key" problem).

Do this:

```
debugonce(stats:::t.test.default)
t.test(dt["x1", A], dt["x2", A])
```

and keep hitting "enter" to see what I mean.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation and for mentioning `debugonce`.